How to style the meter element in chrome
I have a meter styled like so.


meter
{
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px gray solid;
    color:red;
    background: lightgray;
}

meter::meter-bar
{
    background: green;
}

meter::-moz-meter-bar
{
    background: green;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar
{
    background: green;
}
<meter max="40" value="12"></meter>



In Firefox it looks like this:

But in Google Chrome (version 131.0.6778.86 64 bit Windows) it looks like this:

How can I get the Chrome version to look like the Firefox version?

To set the height of meter in Chome, you need to set height in ::webkit-meter-bar. I will provide updated code.


meter
{
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px gray solid;
    color:red;
    background: lightgray;
}

meter::meter-bar
{
    background: green;
}

meter::-moz-meter-bar
{
    background: green;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar
{
    background: lightgray;
    height: calc(2em - 4px); /* Here, I deduct height 4px because border has 4px with top and bottom. */
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
    background: green;
}
<meter max="40" value="12"></meter>




thank you. This does address the height issue, but the colour issues remain.

@MattEllen, I just updated my answer. It is exactly same as your expectation I think.

I'm not seeing anything on firefox.

@0stone0, well, can you check it again?

You'll need to set the meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value to the color you wish.
And apply a full height on meter::-webkit-meter-bar to grow the bar.


meter
{
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px gray solid;
    background: lightgray;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar
{
    height: calc(2em - 4px);
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
    background: green;
}
<meter max="40" value="12"></meter>



